# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x^2e^{1/x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having trouble with this problem:

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x^2e^{1/x}}$

When I evaluate I get 1/(-∞*0), so I am not sure how to evaluate this limit or rewrite it to use LHR (if it is even needed).

The answer is supposed to be 0.

Comment: $1/e^{-1/x}=e^{1/x}$.  Try using that and L'hopitals.

Comment: rewrite your expression as $t^2 e^{t}$ with $t \to \infty$

Comment: I made a mistake in the problem, it is supposed to be e^(1/x) and not e^(-1/x). Sorry!

Comment: HINT:  $$e^{1/x}\ge 1$$for $x>0$.

Comment: Change the expression to 1/ ( e^(ln(x))^2 *e^(1/x)) or 1/(e^(2ln(x)+1/x) or e^(-2ln(x)-1/x). The limit is determined by the limit of the expression

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=1/x$, then apply LHR twice.
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{x^2e^{1/x}}=\lim_{y \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{y^2}{e^y} = \lim_{y \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{2}{e^y}=0$

Comment: How did you get 2/ e^y ?

Comment: apply the L'Hospital rule twice.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that $e^{u}\geq\dfrac{1}{6}u^{3}$ for $u\geq 0$. Then for $x>0$, $e^{-1/x}\leq 6x^{3}$, then $x^{-2}e^{-1/x}\leq 6x$, taking $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$ yields the result.